# How to install specific jdk version on CentOS linux

Tags: linux, centos, java, java-6

I want to install a specific version (1.6.0_23) of jdk on centos. As I am new to linux, how can I do the installation?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need that exact version btw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download needed rpm package from Oracle site http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Then install this package:

```
rpm -ivvh jdk-6u23-linux-amd64.rpm
```

Answer (score -3):

try

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Comment: Centos does not use dpkg nor apt-get, linux != ubuntu.